# Telegram bot won't send message to a user other than who triggered the bot. [sendMessage not working]

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, telegram, telegram-bot

```
const chat_id = req.body.message.chat.id
const dharmaraj = 2xx4xxx5x //My Telegram UID
```

So I have these 2 const declared at top and `chat_id` is ID of group/user who used my bot command. If I use the bot from my personal chat, it does reply. But when someone else use the bot in private or in group, the bot won't alert me about it in Telegram.

Here is the code:

```
console.log(`Post command used by ${user_id}`)

 res.status(200).send({
     method: 'sendMessage',
     dharmaraj,
     text: `Message posted successfully!!`,
     parse_mode: 'Markdown'
 })
```

The `console.log()` statement does work.

[image]

But I don't receive the message from the bot.
I have `started` the bot and have a long chat history as well. So that shouldn't be an issue.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51745624/13130697) but I don't want to use any other package.

**EDIT:**

(1) If I replace it with the `chat_id` itself (ID where the bot was triggered) it will send message in that chat. Problem is to get some text in my personal chat so I know the bot has been used.

(2) I tried embedding the snippet in a `try-catch` but no error there.

(3) Tried replacing UID with the `@username` but no luck.

Comment: `dharmaraj` seems to be your ID, you'll still need to tell telegeram thats a chat id: Try something like: `method: 'sendMessage', chat_id: dharmaraj, ...`

Comment: @0stone0 it does when I run the command in a group and then it sends message to me. But when I replace my ID with with group ID then the command will run if it is ran in group. It wont get triggered from my personal chat

Comment: So you want the bot to send 2 messages as his reply, one tho the user and one to you? Then you should send a second message, the first to `chat_id` to reply, second to your own id?

Comment: @0stone0 I want to use command `/post` from private chat with bot. Then the bot must post the message in the group.

Comment: @0stone0 I replace `dharmaraj` ID with `group_id`... bot has access to messages in group.

Comment: Try editing the question and elaborate it some more, I'm having trouble understanding your real question.

Comment: @0stone0 check now. I want the bot to publish a message by running a command in private chat with bot.

Comment: the private chat is a supergroup and bot has access to its messages? (I guess you should explain your question more clear)

Comment: @AliKhalili yes it's a supergroup and anyways as far as I know all groups are supergroups after an update